# Count of MongoDB aggregation match results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm working with a MongoDB collection that has a lot of duplicate keys. I regularly do aggregation queries to find out what those duplicates are, so that I can dig in and find out what is and isn't different about them.

Unfortunately the database is huge and duplicates are often intentional. What I'd like to do is to find the **count** of keys that have duplicates, instead of printing a result with thousands of lines of output. Is this possible?

(Side Note: I do all of my querying through the shell, so solutions that don't require external tools or a lot of code would be preferred, but I understand that's not always possible.)

Example Records:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "type" : "example", "key" : "111111", "value" : "abc" }
{ "_id" : 2, "type" : "example", "key" : "222222", "value" : "def" }
{ "_id" : 3, "type" : "example", "key" : "222222", "value" : "ghi" }
{ "_id" : 4, "type" : "example", "key" : "333333", "value" : "jkl" }
{ "_id" : 5, "type" : "example", "key" : "333333", "value" : "mno" }
{ "_id" : 6, "type" : "example", "key" : "333333", "value" : "pqr" }
{ "_id" : 7, "type" : "example", "key" : "444444", "value" : "stu" }
{ "_id" : 8, "type" : "example", "key" : "444444", "value" : "vwx" }
{ "_id" : 9, "type" : "example", "key" : "444444", "value" : "yz1" }
{ "_id" : 10, "type" : "example", "key" : "444444", "value" : "234" }
```

Here is the query that I've been using to find duplicates based on `key`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            type: "example"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$key",
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            count: {
                $gt: 1
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Which gives me an output of:

```
{
  "_id": "222222",
  "count": 2
},
{
  "_id": "333333",
  "count": 3
},
{
  "_id": "444444",
  "count": 4
}
```

The result I want to get instead:

```
3
```

Comment: Add the  `{$count:"count"`} after $match.

Comment: @Veeram thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are almost there, just missing the last `$count`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      type: "example"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$key",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      count: {
        $gt: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $count: "count"
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

This appears to be the right solution, but apparently we're still on MongoDB v3.2, and I'm getting an error when trying to use this. I've found another, (more hacky) method that a coworker gave me. I'll post it as another solution.

Answer (score 2):

[Akrion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52502670/8050505) seems to be correct, but I can't test it because we're on an older version of MongoDB. A coworker gave me an alternative solution that works on 3.2 (not sure about other versions).

Adding `.toArray()` will convert the results to an array, and you can then get the size of the array using `.length`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            type: "example"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$key",
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            count: {
                $gt: 1
            }
        }
    }
]).toArray().length
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. You only need the total of documents. However, in the above way, you will receive documents that are not needed.

Comment: No, what I needed was the total number of duplicate keys after a single $match stage. After having learned a lot more about MongoDB, I'm reviewing both this and the accepted answer, and they were correct for my situation.